# How can I run setInterval or a stopwatch system even tab is not focus or browser in sleep? | React & Next Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to run a stopwatch system using next js. But the weird thing I face is that when the tab is not focused, sleep, or inactive, the stopwatch is not running properly. It seems the stopwatch did not run at that time.

Here is how I tried to update each second using setInterval

```
useEffect(() => {
        let interval;
        if (running) {
            console.log("if run change", time)
            interval = setInterval(() => {
                setTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1);
            }, 1000);
        } else if (!running) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }, [running])
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into a service worker - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API

In this case you can simply create a separate script that maintains your timer and then communicates to the parent react app using `postMessage` from the serviceworker when in focus OR you can have a notification that they can click on.

Here is an example to get you started that initiates a chat message interface

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients#examples